# System architecture for committing multiple large records from a single payload across multiple databases

Tags: architecture

I a rest service, I am receiving a large request in a multi-part mime message.  I need to break the parts apart, store the 1st part (the header) in a one database, and store the additional parts, as separate records, in a different database.

Once all parts are in the database the header part can then be available for clients to query.

We haven't decided on database technology yet, although we are primarily a .net shop so sql server is our go-to option, but not necessarily our only option.

Because the payload is large, and we are talking about multiple databases, I'm not sure that transactions are an option.

Is a broker option appropriate or should I be using queues in some way.  I'm looking for some architectural advice.

Answer (score 0):

Most databases have a concept of commit/rollback. It should be possible to handle the conceptual transaction at the application. Ex:

1. Receive request and split into N DB operations to perform.
2. Perform all operations (possibly in parallel for performance reasons).
3. If all succeed, commit and respond with 2XX.
4. If any fail, rollback and respond with 5XX.

Alternatively, the request can be placed in a queue and the result of the operation may be stored in the DB. Ex:

API

1. Receive Request at API, and place in Queue for processing.
2. Respond with place where result can be found (https://restfulapi.net/http-status-202-accepted/)

Backend

1. Pick next message for processing.
2. Perform all operations.
3. If all succeed, commit all and set the 'header' segment to success.
4. If any failed, rollback and only commit the 'header' segment as failed.

**Edit:**

Assuming messages may range in size from 50KB-50MB, it may be worth tweaking the design. There are usually means to increase the maximum message size for queues, but doing this may not be recommended because:

1. Maintaining throughput with larger messages doesn't scale well on the queue server.
2. Processes which can take arbitrarily long make scaling difficult.

One option to address this is to manage the transaction at the Application level. Ex:

API

1. Receive request at API, and generate a transaction ID.
2. Split the large message into N operations to perform.
3. Update the DB with the transaction ID and some metadata to know when all operations are complete (Ex: keep track of total/successes/failures).
4. Write the N messages to relevant queues including transaction ID.
5. Respond with place where result can be found.
6. Only allow client to see header when total = successes.

Backend:

1. Pick next message for processing and perform operation.
2. On success, increment 'successes' and commit.
3. On failure, rollback and increment 'failures'.

Possibly also optimize to skip processing if 'failures' > 0 for a prior message in the same transaction.

Comment: I'm assuming you might be talking about amqp like rabbitmq or kafka or maybe azure service bus.  With those what are the practical limitations on size of entries in the queue?    Or content can range between 100k - 50mb.

Comment: Added an edit. Practical limitations on a queue tend to be related to system specs (ex: memory/network/nodes). There are usually configurations which allow 100K-50M, but it may be worth considering other designs first.

Comment: In your option to address large messages - how do you write N messages to relevant queues while ensuring that all queues get written to successfully?   Also in your last comment you suggested considering other designs.. are you suggesting non-queue oriented designs?

Comment: If a queue write fails, 5XX can be the response + the DB can be updated with the failure. I wasn't suggesting non-queue design in the comment. Queues are most useful when real-time completion is not necessary and there are times where there will be a backlog of work. If the operation does not need to complete realtime, then it will likely be worth using a queue (to allow for occasional increases in throughput).